# MySQL Connection Error with Cpanel Hosting

Tags: mysql, django, cpanel

I'm trying to connect my application with MySQL Database engine on Cpanel hosting platform but every time I tried to run `makemigrations` there's always this long error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 366, in get_new_connection
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 286, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1099, in connect
    self._post_connection()
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1071, in _post_connection
    self.set_charset_collation(self._charset_id)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1016, in set_charset_collation
    ) = CharacterSet.get_charset_info(charset)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/constants.py", line 775, in get_charset_info
    info = cls.get_default_collation(charset)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/constants.py", line 746, in get_default_collation
    raise ProgrammingError(f"Character set '{charset}' unsupported")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Character set '255' unsupported

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/cmsmcs/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/cmsmcs/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 119, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 313, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 284, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 366, in get_new_connection
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 286, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1099, in connect
    self._post_connection()
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1071, in _post_connection
    self.set_charset_collation(self._charset_id)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1016, in set_charset_collation
    ) = CharacterSet.get_charset_info(charset)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/constants.py", line 775, in get_charset_info
    info = cls.get_default_collation(charset)
  File "/home2/cmsmcsc1/virtualenv/cmsmcs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/constants.py", line 746, in get_default_collation
    raise ProgrammingError(f"Character set '{charset}' unsupported")
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (-1, "Character set '255' unsupported", None)
```

Does anyone knows what to do, please?

Comment: What is the full MySQL server version `select version()`? Which version is the python mysql connector?

Comment: can I know while developing in local machine which database were you using with version

Comment: I am using a cpanel hosting service. The application runs correctly on my local machine but I'm trying to deploy and I run into this issue. I've tried to run mysqlclient==2.1.0 which is what the requirement is showing me but there's an error also.

Comment: I used postgres for development, but I couldn't install pycopg2 when I tried to install requirements so I thought I should switch to MySQL. I want to start with a clean database and my models are empty too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it it will definitely helps you

run the command in your Cpanel Hosting Terminal

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python==8.0.29
```